# Laravel query with multiple parent ids

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I would like to know what the most effective way to select all the deliverables from all the sprints within a certain project would be. Before I would just query them all and use blade.php for loops and if statements to filter which deliverables I need. What is the most effective way in php to perform this task?

Sprint Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\SprintRequest;

use Reponse;

use App\Sprint;
use App\Deliverable;
use App\Project;

class SprintController extends Controller
{
    private function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('role:admin', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
}

    public function index($project_id)
    {
        $project = Project::findOrFail($project_id);
        $sprints = $project->sprints()->get();
        $deliverables = array();

        foreach ($sprints as $sprint) {
            array_push($deliverables, $sprint->deliverables()->get());
        }

        $amount = 0;
        $completed = 0;
        foreach ($deliverables as $deliverable) {
            if ($deliverable->complete == '1' && $deliverable->sprint_id == $sprint->id && $deliverable->inactive == '0') {
                $completed += 1;
                $amount += 1;
            }
            else if ($deliverable->sprint_id == $sprint->id && $deliverable->inactive == '0') {
                $amount += 1;
            }
        }

        return view('sprints.index', compact('sprints', 'deliverables', 'amount', 'completed', 'project'));
    }
    public function create($project_id)
    {
        $project = Project::findOrFail($project_id);
        $sprint = new Sprint;

        return view('sprints.create', compact('project', 'sprint'));
    }

    public function store(SprintRequest $request, $project_id)
    {
        $project = Project::findOrFail($project_id);
        $sprint = new Sprint;

        $sprint->name = $request->name;

        $project->sprints()->save($sprint);

        return "success";
    }

    public function edit($project_id, $sprint_id)
    {
        $project = Project::findOrFail($project_id);
        $sprint = $project->sprints()->findOrFail($sprint_id);

        return view('sprints.edit', compact('project', 'sprint'));
    }

    public function update(SprintRequest $request, $project_id, $sprint_id)
    {
        $project = Project::findOrFail($project_id);
        $sprint = $project->sprints()->findOrFail($sprint_id);

        $sprint->name = $request->name;

        $sprint->save();

        return "success";
    }   


}
```

This is what i have so far but it gives me this error

> BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 748:
>   Target [App\Http\Controllers\SprintController] is not instantiable.

Thanks

Comment: show the SprintController code

Comment: What would you filter in blade?

Comment: Shoudn't eager load deliverables?

Comment: @EddyTheDove Before I would only show the deliverables that were in the sprints relating to that certain project even though all the deliverables from every project was being passed to the view

Comment: @train_fox what do you mean by eager?

Comment: See this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

your constructor is private that's why you actually have this error .